# Voltage supply used in main supply

Tags: electrical-engineering

why should we use voltage rms (V rms) besides peak voltage (V peak) for main supply? What is the different that might be occur?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity: The rms voltage multiplied by the rms current is the power. Also rms voltage and current definitions allow for deviations from pure sinusoid time dependences.